# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirect issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have currently hit a bit of an issue with redirecting users with .htaccess and was wondering if anyone could help me.

### 1. Background:

I currently have a rather long domain name for the sake of this question lets refer to it as `mylongdomainname.com` now on this domain I have a subdomain that I use to host files, pictures etc to show friends or share with people this is `files.mylongdomainname.com`
now obviously the URL can get quite long as I have different directories and files. so to help reduce a bit of space I purchased another short domain, lets refer to this as `small.me` now what I want to do is use .htaccess and a simple PHP file to redirect `small.me` to `files.mylongdomainname.com` and pass on a file reference.

Example:
`small.me/pictures/example.jpg` should redirect to `files.mylongdomainname.com/pictures/example.jpg`

### 2. The problem

Basically I am unsure on the exact rewrite rule I would need to acomplish this. obviously I need a rule that will allow anything after `small.me/` to be sent with the GET method to the index file which would then redirect the user accordingly. So that means that the rewrite rule will have to allow all letters, numbers and valid file name symbols to be used. I'm sure it's simple but after looking at a few tutorials and mod_rewrite help sites I still have no idea how to accomplish this.

### 3. The Code

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?file_location=$1 [L]
```

*obviously wrong*

index.php

```
<?php

    //Get the requested files location.
    $file_location = $_GET['file_location'];


    //Redirect the user to the file.
    header('refresh:2; url=http://files.mylongdomainname.com/' . $file_location);

?>
```

### 4. Notes

I am aware I could just use a URL shortener, but because I am awkward I would rather it just went through my own domain, so please don't comment or answer telling me to use a shortener or to use a service like dropbox.

---

So can anybody help me by providing the right rule? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .htaccess you can simply use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://small.me/?$1 [L]
```

No need for the PHP file if that's all you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this:

Picture to be shared: `http://files.mylongdomainname.com/pictures/me/troll.jpg`

Desired URL: `http://small.me/pictures/me/troll.jpg`

Remove the PHP file, just Place this in `small.me`'s  htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://files.mylongdomainname.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've accepted Andres answer as he was the first to post. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The following in your .htaccess file should be all you need (no PHP file needed):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://files.mylongdomainname.com/$1 [RL]
```

For more information and examples see the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've accepted Andres answer as he was the first to post. But thank you anyway!